# Извлечь из строки подстроку в swift

Tags: swift

Есть строка

```
"blabla, blablabla; superkey=SUPERVALUE; blabla, blablabla, bla; blabla=blabla"
```

Как извлечь подстроку `SUPERVALUE`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring

Comment: Вот набор вменяемых примеров: [ссылка](https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-swift).

Answer (score 3):

### Решение

Можно сделать очень просто:

```swift
let str = "blabla, blablabla; superkey=SUPERVALUE; blabla, blablabla, bla; blabla=blabla"
let superkey = str.components(separatedBy: "superkey=").last?.components(separatedBy: ";").first
```

### Минусы решения:

Это решение не очень эффективное, если Вам надо парсить большие строки и в большом количестве.

### Когда рекомендуется использовать:

Если строка всегда в схожем формате и небольшая и парсить часто не требуется, то по производительности вряд ли сможете отличить от любого другого.